# Journey Data Configuration Questions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

I am helping a client address a few journey optimization issues, and would like some guidance on 2 items I'm working through.

**SFDC Triggered Entry Journey DE:** I understand with SFDC triggered journeys, the journey DE is automatically created in Contact Builder. My client has a use case where they would like to track specific engagement within the journey. So I would like to use the Update Contact activity to update engagement field values in the journey DE (e.g. after contact passes first email step, Update Contact to update a custom 'SentEmail1' field from 'False' to 'True). So I would like to understand if you are able to **add additional custom fields to the auto-populated journey DE**? And if not, I'm thinking of creating a separate journey engagement tracking DE and linking it to the journey DE via an attribute group. Please advice on the best approach here

**Tracking contacts across Journeys:** My client would also like to be able to track contacts in specific journeys for targeting/suppression purposes from other sends. The solution I am thinking of is to create a 'Journey Tracking' DE, and similar to the above, use Update Contact activity to inject them into this DE. It's straight forward with journey entry and entry date, but I would like to understand if there is a **simple way to stamp the journey exit date**. It will not suffice just adding a Update Contact step at the end of the journey since contacts may exit upon meeting goal/exit criteria. The only way I can think of right now is setting up queries reviewing each journey on a daily basis and stamping the tracking DE with today's date if contact is no longer in the journey. but this is a more complex and technical solution requiring SQL, so I would like to know if there is an easier or more declarative solution here.

Thank you in advance!